# jQuery dynamic add button plus and minus

Tags: jquery

[image]
Here what I want is, if i click + button another field should be displayed,changing + to -.1st field should not be deleted(+button should remain same).But in my code 1st row is deleting. Please correct my code.

[image]

When clicked on +button , another field should be added and button should change from "+" to "-". And last added row should be deleted if clicked on - button. But in my code 1st row is deleting. As shown in the image posted here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(' button[name="addnewbro"]').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('+') > -1) {
      var cp = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
      $(cp).find('button[name="addnewbro"]').text('-');
      $(cp).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent().val(''));
      $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="brother" style="width:40%">
  <div class="bro">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_Company" placeholder="Company/School Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_l" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_3" placeholder="Address Line 3" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_city" placeholder="City" />
        </div>
        <div class="pbro">
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="bzip" name="bzip" placeholder="PIN" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="btaluk" name="btaluk" placeholder="Taluk" size="10" />
            <input type="text" name="bdist" id="bdist" placeholder="District" size="10" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="bstate" id="bstate" placeholder="State" size="15" />

          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="bcountry" id="bcountry" placeholder="Country" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button name="addnewbro">
          +
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: please, tell what is correct behaviour:
behaviour 1 ( on start you have only one element  with plus => a element )
1) you click the plus => receiving 2 elements. first one a element with minus and new one ( last one ) b element - with plus
2) you click the plus second time => receiving 3 elements a, b elemenets - with minus and the last one with plus.

when you click minus on b element you should receive:
1) a,b elements OR
2) a, c elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, this is something you are looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(' button[name="addnewbro"]').live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('+') > -1) {
      var cp = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
      $(cp).find('button[name="addnewbro"]').text('-');
      $(cp).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent().val(''));
      $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().next().remove();
      $('button[name="addnewbro"]:last').text('+');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="brother" style="width:40%">
  <div class="bro">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_Company" placeholder="Company/School Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_l" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_3" placeholder="Address Line 3" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="BWorking_city" placeholder="City" />
        </div>
        <div class="pbro">
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="bzip" name="bzip" placeholder="PIN" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="btaluk" name="btaluk" placeholder="Taluk" size="10" />
            <input type="text" name="bdist" id="bdist" placeholder="District" size="10" />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="bstate" id="bstate" placeholder="State" size="15" />

          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="bcountry" id="bcountry" placeholder="Country" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button name="addnewbro">
          +
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Added example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(' button[name="addnewbro"]').live('click', function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('+') > -1) {
          var cp = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
          $(cp).find('button[name="addnewbro"]').text('-');
          $(cp).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent().val(''));
          $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
        } else {
          var $container = $( this ).parent().parent().parent();
          $container.children("div:last-child").remove();
          $container.children("div:last-child" ).find('button[name="addnewbro"]').text("+"); 
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bro">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_Company" placeholder="Company/School Name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_l" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_3" placeholder="Address Line 3" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_city" placeholder="City" />
      </div>
      <div class="pbro">
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="bzip" name="bzip" placeholder="PIN" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="btaluk" name="btaluk" placeholder="Taluk" size="10" />
          <input type="text" name="bdist" id="bdist" placeholder="District" size="10" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="bstate" id="bstate" placeholder="State" size="15" />

        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="bcountry" id="bcountry" placeholder="Country" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button name="addnewbro">
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didnt worked. added field should be deleted not 1st field. But in my code 1st  field is deleting.And for added field - button should be displayed.

Comment: It won't work with the latest version of jquery. Deprecated after 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Answer Updated with last JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(document).on('click', 'button[name="addnewbro"]', function() {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('+') > -1) {
          var cp = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
          $(cp).find('button[name="addnewbro"]').text('-');
          $(cp).insertBefore($(this).parent().parent().val(''));
          $(this).parent().parent().find('input').val('');
        } else {
          var $container = $( this ).parent().parent().parent();
          $container.children("div:last-child").remove();
          $container.children("div:last-child" ).find('button[name="addnewbro"]').text("+"); 
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bro">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_Company" placeholder="Company/School Name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_l" placeholder="Address Line 1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_2" placeholder="Address Line 2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_address_3" placeholder="Address Line 3" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="BWorking_city" placeholder="City" />
      </div>
      <div class="pbro">
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="bzip" name="bzip" placeholder="PIN" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="btaluk" name="btaluk" placeholder="Taluk" size="10" />
          <input type="text" name="bdist" id="bdist" placeholder="District" size="10" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="bstate" id="bstate" placeholder="State" size="15" />

        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="bcountry" id="bcountry" placeholder="Country" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button name="addnewbro">
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```